# free Facebook comments module on product page of magento

Tags: magento-1.7, extension-methods, facebook-comments

i have tried [Facebook Comment by Magestore](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/facebook-comment-7731.html). and properly configured on backendv with valid facebook app id.but not showing any fb comment option on frontend. What is wrong going on? module is not working well??? if it is then suggest me good module for facebook comment integration on product page.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free module with admin controller: [Facebook-Comments](https://github.com/Mo7amad7amdy/facebook-comments)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can move your `layout\fbcomment.xml` and `template\fbcomment\fbcomment.phtml` on your template directory `\app\design\frontend\[your template dir]\default\`